# Exclude folders in batch-copy-script

Tags: batch-file, file-copying

I am using a batch file on a USB stick to backup my pictures. I use the following command:

```
for /r C:\ %%x in (*.jpg *.png *.gif) do @copy /y %%x .
```

I want to exclude files in the mailfolder WINDOWS and PROGRAM FILES.

Does anyone have an idea how I can do this with a batch file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Drop `COPY` and use [`ROBOCOPY`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) which exists in Windows Vista+ & is downloadable for prior versions.

It supports `/XD` to exclude specific directories & `/XF` to exclude file masks at the command line.

E.g.

```
robocopy.exe c:\ c:\destination\ *.jpg *.png *.gif /xd "Program files" "windows" /S
```

(Note this will recreate the directory structure in c:\destination\, which thinking about it may not be what you want)

Comment: Do you have an example fitting this issue. I tried it but only got error message because of some parameters it didn't accept (that was listet on Microsofts pages).

Comment: Can i set the standing folder as destination any easy way?

Comment: You mean the current dir? use a period `.`

Comment: Ok, thanks :) It's say it copying now, but the files doesn't appera. Weird. Btw, can I use many sources, like C: and D:?

Comment: It copying to C:\windows\system32 instead of the standing dir with .

Comment: This saved me so much time. Worked perfectly for copying my work directory onto a backup drive and excluding all my `node_modules` folders within each directory which don't need copying! +1

Answer (score 2):

Turn `copy` into `xcopy` and then you can use it's `/EXCLUDE` switch

```
@xcopy %%x /y /EXCLUDE:\WINDOWS\
```

See `xcopy /?` for the details.

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>for /R C:\ %x in (*.jpg *.png *.gif) do @xcopy %x /y /EXCLUDE:\WINDOWS\
Ugyldig antall parametere.
Ugyldig antall parametere.
Ugyldig antall parametere.
Ugyldig antall parametere.
Ugyldig antall parametere.
Ugyldig antall parametere.
Ugyldig antall parametere. (illegal number of parameters)

Comment: Did you read `xcopy /?`? that will give you the switch details.

Comment: Ofcourse :) But I did it exactly as it was explained: for /R C:\ %x in (*.jpg *.png *.gif) do @xcopy %x /y /EXCLUDE:\WINDOWS\

Comment: Just checking :) In that case I'm not sure, I would prob go with Alex's answer.

Comment: Since I finally have enough rep to comment a year later...:
@xcopy %%x /y /EXCLUDE:exclude.txt
where exclude.txt has: WINDOWS\

to exclude the WINDOWS folder.
The EXCLUDE switch requires ' a list of files containing strings'