# Xcopy does not copy all files

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a tool for our department that generates a protocol from an Atlassian Datasource.
Because in some cases the tool didn't worked when started from the company's netdrive, a colleague wrote the following batch file to simply copy the relevant files locally, which lead to a working program for all.

```
mkdir C:\QuickProtocol\
mkdir C:\QuickProtocol\Templates\
mkdir C:\QuickProtocol\In\
mkdir C:\QuickProtocol\Out\
mkdir C:\QuickProtocol\Templates\Protokoll-Dateien\

XCOPY \\*NetDrivePath*\QuickProtocol.exe  C:\QuickProtocol\ /y 
XCOPY \\*NetDrivePath*\QuickProtocol.pdb  C:\QuickProtocol\ /d /y 
XCOPY \\*NetDrivePath*\Languages.xml      C:\QuickProtocol\ /d /y 
XCOPY \\*NetDrivePath*\PrimeCore.dll      C:\QuickProtocol\ /d /y 
XCOPY \\*NetDrivePath*\Templates          C:\QuickProtocol\Templates\ /d /y /s
```

But now a colleague that changed departments, but has still access to the files on the netdrive, tried the batch file again.
Strangely in his case, as well as in the case of some other colleagues who reported to him, the batch file only copy's the Templates Folder and creates the directories named above.
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: its hot shared - the net drive path. or only templates is shared. try dir \\*NetDrivePath*\  And xcopy is good to copy sub folders. if your copying one file like the first 3 just use copy.

Comment: Just a guess, could the topic of user rights on the netdrive have something to do with the problem?

Comment: Variables are in % not *. And you havn't set %NetDrivePath% anywhere.

Comment: *NetDrive* is just a replacement for the real netdrivepath, in the original the Path is included, but the path is very long, and not interesting so I replaced it, sorry for the confusion

Comment: i dont 100%ly get what you mean with hot shared. The Netdrive it self is heavly used yes, the specific folder where the files are located, does not have a high number of accesses, i think

Comment: Are you on a 64 bit system?  There is a problem with some 64-bit versions of window in that they do not see all the files that a 32-bit system sees.  I can't find the reference for this.  The fix is to use xcopy on a 32 bit system.

Comment: @cup it wouldn't apply here, 32 bit programs get directed to 32 bit folders. Asking what files in c:\windows\system32 will get you the files in the 32 bit system32 folder. See File Redirection in Development Guides is WSDK.

Comment: ``File System Redirector
The %windir%\System32 directory is reserved for 64-bit applications. Most DLL file names were not changed when porting to 64-bit, so 32-bit applications must use a different directory as their System32 directory. WOW64 hides this difference using a file system redirector.
Whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access %windir%\System32, the access is redirected to a new directory, %windir%\SysWOW64. `

Comment: @user2482566 If your netpath has spaces it won't work. Can you type it at command line.

Comment: Meant to say : maybe its not shared, so as noodles says open a cmd (command prompt) type dir then the full drive, if it has spaces then put it in quotes. example : dir "\\server 1\share\my pro\sub folder\"

Comment: there are no spaces in the path, just a "_" a "." and the rest are normal characters. what i dont understand is, that for some users the batchfile works and for others, it only copy's the templates folder

Comment: Put a `pause` on the last line and ask the affected user to launch it.  Report or follow up on the error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers, in my case changing `Xcopy` to `Copy` for the few single file Copys helped, at least it seems so. Hopefully it stays this way^^

Answer (score 3):

The reason for failure on copying of the files could be missing permissions to read the contents of the files.

The Microsoft documentation about [Permissions for files and folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc787794(v=ws.10)) explains in details the possible permissions on NTFS drives. The Microsoft documentation [How permissions are handled when you copy and move files and folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/windows-security/permissions-on-copying-moving-files) describes how Windows Explorer handles file and folder permissions in different situations.

It is possible that users have only **Traverse Folder/List Folder** permissions which means they can view which subfolders and files are in a folder and browse also to subfolders. In other words the users have the permissions to list the directory tree.

But if the users have not additionally the **Read Data** permission, they can't open a file for reading. In this case also `copy` and `xcopy` fail to copy the files as of no permission to read the data of a file.

It is possible that running the application directly from shared network folder failed because of same reason. The users have permissions to **Traverse Folder/List Folder/Execute File**, but no permissions for **Read Data** and therefore the application failed to read the files in the directory.

I suggest that one of the users having trouble should try to open the file `Languages.xml` in `Notepad` or in `Internet Explorer` directly from the shared network folder. An error message is shown by those applications if the user does not have the required **Read Data** permission.

It could be also helpful to append to the batch file at bottom the command `Pause`, change `@echo off` at top of the batch file to `@echo on` if that line exists at all, and then execute the batch file. Now the user can view the executed commands and also all errors occurring during batch file execution.

Answer (score 0):

Because of permission errors I used `robocopy` instead of `copy` or `xcopy`

More info here:

[Exclude folders in batch-copy-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976848/exclude-folders-in-batch-copy-script)